# Override some DNS records and delegate others to another nameserver

Tags: domain-name-system

I'm starting playing with nameservers.
Currently I have:

- A domain: mydomain.com
- Access for writing the whois ns records.
- Access for writing DNS records at the domain hosting provider. **nsX.foo.com**
- A shared (hostC) hosting which cPanel writes in the nameserver of **nsX.bar.com**

Basically I want the following structure:

```
hostA.mydomain.com -> hostA
hostB.mydomain.com -> hostB
hostC.mydomain.com -> hostC
mydomain.com       -> hostC
*.mydomain.com     -> hostC
```

Whats the correct way of configuring this?

By the way I have configured the following records

```
hostA.mydomain.com IN A [IP_OF_hostA]     (at foo.com nameservers)
hostB.mydomain.com IN A [IP_OF_hostB]     (at foo.com nameserver)
```

But now I dont know how to specify that `@.mydomain.com` and `*.mydomain.com` are resolved by the `ns1.bar.com` and `ns2.bar.com`, and it is hard to try with the delays after editing the records.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mydomain.com. IN NS nsX.foo.com.
hostA.mydomain.com. IN A [IP_OF_hostA]
hostB.mydomain.com. IN A [IP_OF_hostB]
*.mydomain.com. IN NS nsX.bar.com.
```